# Configure sftp to switch to another user on login

Tags: ssh, sftp, su

If I have a server with the web space owned by user A, is it possible to configure ssh or sftp to automatically switch a user logging in via SFTP as a different user B to su to user A, chrooted to the web space? I don't want user A to be able to log in via SSH or SFTP. Neither user gets sudo or root access, and root cannot log in via SSH or SFTP.

Comment: You don't want user A to be able to login using SSH or SFTP but you want user B to behave as user A. What's the difference?